# What is the single word that means "part of speech"

Tags: word-request, parts-of-speech

Part of speech refers to the linguistic categories for words or lexical items, such as *noun*, *verb*, *adjective* and *adverb*, etc.

Which is the single word meaning "part of speech" exactly?

Comment: There is no single word. The more usual term today is *word class*, and where the context is sufficiently narrow you may use *class* alone. For example: “A participle is a verb form which participates in two classes simultaneously, both *verb* and another.”

Comment: Why was this considered "not a real question"? I think it's pretty clear what's being answered. It may perhaps be off-topic, and it doesn't have a good answer, but I think its a real question.

Comment: I don't even see how it would be off-topic. Just because the answer is "there is no such word" doesn't make it not a valid question. It just means the answer is "sorry, there is no such word". (Assuming that's the answer. I don't know of any such word, but there might be a word I'm unfamiliar with.)

Comment: @KenB It seems to be that is clear what it means, and there is also an answer for it. Maybe it was better if the question asked another term to say "part of speech" without to request a single word. Since "part of speech" is still understood nowadays, I can understand the question has been considered not much helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Jay Considering there is an alternative, an answer can be given. StoneyB's comment would be an answer.

Comment: @Jay I would consider this more appropriate for English.SE, or at least worth discussing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think there is a good answer. StoneyB suggested "word class", but I disagree; I think that's an overlapping term, but not a synonym, and I don't think that it's "the more usual term". The average English speaker (in my experience in the US) would simply use "part of speech".

Comment: Additionally, "not helpful for future readers" != "should be closed". Plenty of SE questions are very specific to a situation, but are perfectly valid questions and good fits for the various sites.

Comment: @KenB Given the context, there are alternatives to "part of speech"; this doesn't mean to necessarily provide a synonym. If I ask for a single word when there isn't a single word I can use, I think my question is probably too localized. Imagine I ask a single word to say "the moon of August you see right after it rained, and a breeze caresses your face"; the fact there isn't such a word is probably not relevant for future readers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's not what localized means. The fact that your question doesn't have a answer doesn't make it too localized at all.

Comment: @KenB It is localized because no other users would be interested of knowing a single word to say "the moon of August you see right after it rained, and a breeze caresses your face"; the fact there isn't a single word is an extra. If the answer is simply _no_, I doubt the question is going to be helpful to future users.

Comment: Also, "not helpful to future readers" **is** a reason for closing a question. The "too localized" closing reason is described as, "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors."

Comment: @KenB You're quite right that *word class* is not the more usual term, just the more usual term among academic grammarians. I think however it is a synonym; the fact that the people who use *word class* recognize somewhat different classes than the POS folks isn't really relevant, since the POS classes have varied over time and geography.

Comment: Although I wouldn't close it for this reason, I don't think *single word requests* make a lot of sense on ELL.  Wouldn't it be a lot more useful to know the *usual way of expressing something* than to ask "How do I express something under an artificial constraint which I will never be under when attempting to actually use the English language?"

Comment: The single word is very useful in cases that the usual way(part of speech) is too long which may not suitable, for the purpose rather than just expressing something. For this purpose, the synonym "class" is just what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the discussion that has happened in the above comments:

1. **There is no general single-word replacement** for "part of speech" that has any real usefulness.
2. If you want the average English speaker to understand what you mean, just say "part of speech".
3. If you are speaking with academic grammarians, it may be more appropriate to use the term "word class", and in some *very specific* circumstances, if everyone involved is paying attention, you may be able to get away with just "class", which is a one word replacement, though it is really just an abbreviated form of the longer, two-word term.